# Add Vertex tool is latching to end vertex from ~100m away

Tags: nolimits-2

I have recently started playing NoLimits2 and am currently trialing it on the demo version. I am trying to finish a coaster but I am having trouble building the track because my 'Add Vertex' tool keeps snapping / latching to the end vertex, as shown in this image...
[image: 'Add Vertex' Latching to End Vertex]

As you can see, the white line is extending ~100m from where the end vertex is. Is there any way I can disable this so it only snaps to the start vertex (the triangle one), and not the end one (the rectangle one)?

Sorry if I sound like a noob, but I can't think of any other way to describe this, and I can't find any results on the internet because I don't know what to search for...

Thanks in advance for any help, it will be greatly appreciated :D

PS: I am running this on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Platform tags are specifically for when a question is about the platform itself, or if a game differs depending on the platform.  Adding a specific tag for exposure is not the way we organize questions.

Comment: @Frank fine then, not like it was gonna be answered anyway.